# Visual studio code analysis for generated files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, code-analysis

Can somebody tell me why code analysis shows issues from generated files? I do check option as here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd742298.aspx

I think it has to do with the fact that I use TT tempate with my Entity framework models. But those files have  tags on them..

Comment: Not sure what "tags" might mean.  The code generator must output the [GeneratedCode] attribute on the generated code to allow the analyzer to recognize that it should ignore the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you have your TT templates output the following into the header?

```
//<autogenerated/>
```

Or to be more specific to certain items in file:

```
[GeneratedCode("MyTool", "1.0")]
public partial class GeneratedModel
{
...
```

Comment: Yes, I made TT template to output attribute. Then code analysis stopped looking at those. comment on top doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: file header comment with a - "auto-generated" is how StyleCop's "Style Analysis" supposedly ignores files.

Comment: I couldn't make the first one work in VS2012 Code Analysis.  The second one however was perfect.  Thanks.