# Cannot prevent "Code Analysis" warnings for

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, code-generation, code-analysis

I am using T4 to generate some code. The code will be in a class called "MyClass.generated.cs" and typical output will look like this.

```
//<autogenerated/>
namespace MyNamespace
{
    using System;
    using System.CodeDom.Compiler;

    [GeneratedCode("T4", "1.0.0.0")]
    public partial class MyClass: SomeBaseClass
    {
        private SomeBaseClass myBackingField;
    }
}
```

However, even though the class is decorated with the [GeneratedCodeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.generatedcodeattribute.aspx), I still get a Code Analysis warning as follows:

> Field 'MyNamespace.MyClass.myBackingField' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null

I have ensure that the **Project Properties** → **Code Analysis** → "Suppress results from generated code (managed only)" checkbox is checked.

Please note that I understand the meaning of the warning - I just want to know how to suppress it :)

**Possible solutions**
I could modify my generator to use Suppressions to suppress specific warnings, but this is extra work that I shouldn't have to do (as generated code should be ignored by Code Analysis).

**Related Questions**

- [Visual studio code analysis for generated files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299583/visual-studio-code-analysis-for-generated-files)

**EDIT with background context**
The actual generated code is essentially a wrapper around `SomeBaseClass`. There are 100+ types in a namespace, and I want to change the behaviour of a subset of those. There are other warnings being generated as well - I just used this one as an example. Consider for example, if there is a property `SomeBaseClass.MyObsoleteProperty`, which is decorated with the `ObsoleteAttribute`. My code generater would still create a `MyClass.MyObsoleteProperty` which would raise a Code Analysis warning.

Another example would be where the `SomeBaseClass` (which is from a 3rd-party) would itself raise Code Analysis warnings if they had bothered to check for them (maybe the class is not CLS-compliant, for example). My wrapper will recreate any errors they have (and that would actually be the desired behaviour).

Comment: Well *is* anything going to assign a value to `myBackingField`? Would it actually make sense for your generated code to have a constructor which sets the field? (And make it readonly at the same time.)

Comment: Hi Jon - basically, there are 100+ generated classes, and I'm going to be implementing partial classes for about half of them. For that half, yes, they will have the field set. The reason I generate all 100 is that I'm using a single T4 template to generate a class for every member of a specific namespace.

Comment: Well it sounds like you should either live with the warning, or go to the trouble of having two separate templates. After all, having a field you don't need in the other half of the classes is far from ideal.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've added a bit more explanation about what I'm doing to hopefully make it clearer why I want to suppress warnings - I've given some other examples of warnings I face that I hope make it clear I have to suppress, rather than fix... Regardless, Code Analysis *should* ignore generated code (the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd742298.aspx) make that clear) so I don't understand why this is not working.

Comment: Thanks for the extra context - hopefully it'll be useful to others too. Unfortunately I don't have an answer for you :(

Comment: @JonSkeet I've stumped Jon Skeet :) That's made my day! Also, I figured it out in the end (see answer - I was being slightly thick), so double w00ts.

Comment: Well, now that we know that the premise of the question was wrong... you did explicitly state that it was a Code Analysis warning :)

Comment: @JonSkeet The first rule of Stack Overflow is don't trust the question setter :P. The second rule is "No smoking".

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out - this is not a Code Analysis warning - it's a compiler warning.

Therefore, the only way to disable it is to modify the generator to enclose the class in pragma directives to [suppress compiler warnings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/441722ys%28VS.80%29.aspx), e.g

```
#pragma warning disable warning-list

// Now generate some code

#pragma warning restore warning-list
```

**WARNING**
Note that this is a dangerous feature - compiler warnings are there for a reason! Try and limit your use of it to as small a section as possible.

More information can be found at
[Suppressing "is never used" and "is never assigned to" warnings in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820985/suppressing-is-never-used-and-is-never-assigned-to-warnings-in-c-sharp)

List of compiler warnings and errors [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228296(v=vs.90).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean

```
#pragma warning disable 
// generated code
#pragma warning restore
```

the "warning-list" is a placeholder in MSDN documentation for something like "c0605,c0403,c3498" etc